# In Vimscript, how to skip over elements in a destructuring assignment from a list?

Tags: vim, destructuring

Vimscript has something like destructuring assignment for lists. For example:

```
:let [a,b,c] = [1,2,3]
```

What if I don't care about the first element but I still want to bind `b` and `c`? Is there some "wildcard" that I can use to avoid giving a name to the `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign those fields to a variable name that makes it clear you're ignoring those values. The `_` variable is a great convention for that.

```
let [_, b, c] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Or, to ignore the first two terms:

```
let [_, _, c] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Note you can use it more than once in a [`:let-unpack`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-unpack) assignment.

In some languages, such as Python, the `_` variable special, in that assignments to it are not stored anywhere. That's not the case in Vimscript, a variable with that name is valid and does exist. But if you're performing this assignment from inside a function (which is likely to be the case), then the variable scope will be limited to that function and the namespace pollution shouldn't be concerning.

---

Here's a real life [example usage](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/v3.2/autoload/fugitive.vim#L3871) from the well known vim-figitive plug-in by tpope:

```
let [_, to, changes; __] = matchlist(a:line, '^ \(.\{-\}\) \+|\zs \(.*\)$')
```

Note it uses the `;` syntax to ignore all fields from the fourth onwards (that's useful to know when unpacking large lists.) It uses `_` to ignore the first field and `__` to ignore the rest. (Note that using `_` for both would have been fine as well.)

The Vim documentation also makes references to using `_` as a name for a variable to be ignored. For an [example usage of `map()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#map%28%29):

> If you do not use "key" you can use a short name:
>
> ```
> call map(myDict, {_, val -> 'item: ' . val})
> ```

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution is to use the black hole register:

```
let [@_,b,c]=[1,2,3]
```

It seems that you can use it more than once without problems:

```
let [@_,@_,c]=[1,2,3]
```

See `:h "_`.